# Using Drawing Manager on Google Maps API v3 after Zooming/Scaling the Div?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, css, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to get my head around using the drawing manager of google maps API V3 (drawing rectangles). After scaling the google maps canvas (the containing div) using -webkit-transform
like this

```
 var transform = ['scale(' + 0.5 + ')'];
 $("#map_canvas").css('-webkit-transform', transform.join(' '));
```

the point where I begin drawing the rectangles seem to be displaced on the map. What I mean by being displaced is the intended place to draw the rectangle is somehow displaced by an offset. The end result is that the rectangle appears somewhere else. I understand this displacement of the rectangle is due to scaling of the div. Can somebody help me with some sort of solution to get around this and make the drawing manager work even after scaling? let me know if you have more questions. Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can avoid scaling entirely by giving dynamic height and width (in percentage).

So if you want to display the map div in the 80% of the viewable area you can do so by giving the following -

```
<div id="MAP_DIV" style="height:80%;width:80%;"></div>
```

This circumvents the scaling issue and consequently the "displaced offset" issue.

But I strongly suggest that you move the in-line styling to a separate .css file for reusability and code maintenance.

Hope it helps.